# iOS 13 Adding a UIWindow with shadow

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to add a UIWindow with shadow and corners in iOS 13. My UIWindow looks like this:

```
- UIWindow
  - backgroundView
  - containerView
    - topContainerView(containers for avatar and nickname)
    - replyView
    - ......
```

Currently, I add corners with UIBezierPath in my containerView, and add shadow in my backgroundView. It works perfectly under iOS 12. But in iOS 13, it does not work.

Expected :

[image: Expected image]

Currently:

[image: Currently image]

Any suggestions and ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the UIDropShadowView under iOS 13 defaults its clipsToBounds to true.

To fix this, manually set its clipsToBounds property to false.

```
window.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.clipsToBounds = false
```